# How to perform text selection inside images in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm working on a React Native app that utilizes Vision Camera for capturing photos, and I aim to enable users to select text from these photos, akin to the functionality found on iPhones. Thus, I prefer not to employ an image processor like Firebase ML Kit; it's a preliminary step.

[image: Here's what I mean:]